# App.xaml in class library

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have created a windows phone 7 custom class library, in that I have created App.xaml and App.xaml.cs files also(I have renamed them as MiEngineApp.xaml, MiEngineApp.xaml.cs and my class library's name is MiEngine). I have referenced the class library in my application.

Now in my application, I want to wrte App.xaml.cs class derived from my class library's App.xaml.cs class(that is MiEngineApp.xaml.cs). When I created the project, App.xaml.cs was created by default. It is by default extending Application class, I just chaged this to MiEngineApp(Application -> MiEngineApp). After doing this I compiled my application, it gives an error in the App.g.i.cs file. The error message is "Partial declarations of 'MiApp.App' must not specify different base classes". How to solve this error!.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You also have to change the App.xaml file. So this will be your MiEngine.xaml

```
<Application xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
             x:Class="MiEngine.MiEngineApp"
             >
    <Application.Resources>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

and MiEngine.xaml.cs:

```
namespace MiEngine
{
    public partial class MiEngineApp : Application
    {

        public MiEngineApp()
        {
```

This will be the App.xaml that inherits from (extends) MiEngine.xaml:

```
<z:MiEngineApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
             x:Class="SilverlightApplication6.App"

             xmlns:z="clr-namespace:MiEngine;assembly=MiEngine"
             >
    <z:MiEngineApp.Resources>

    </z:MiEngineApp.Resources>
</z:MiEngineApp>
```

Note the use of the `z` namespace so that i can reference the base class.
And the codebehind for that:

```
namespace SilverlightApplication6
{
    public partial class App : MiEngineApp
    {

        public App()
        {
```

Comment: @saikamesh, sorry my first answer was slightly misleading, so i took the time to do a proper sample using the same names you've got (this builds and runs).

Comment: @slugster : Great!!!. Works fine. Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation.Before posting this question, I searched on the net to see if I can find a tutorial for this. but did not find anything. Can you please tell me from where I can read about all these stuffs(like z namespace)

Comment: @saikamesh, there's not too much to it, they are basically the equivalent of the `using [namespace]` statement in your C# code. VS should give you a big intellisense list when you've typed the `=` sign, so you can just scroll down and choose the appropriate entry - if the one you want is not there then you probably need to add a reference to that assembly or project.

Comment: @slugster : MainPage's constructor is getting called two times. Can you guess what may cause this.(I have created my application's App class by extending ClassLibrary's App class)

Comment: @saikamesh - i couldn't guess as that is most likely due to an issue with your code. If you create a new question with the stripped down xaml and cs files then everyone can take a look (are you sure you are not inadvertantly creating two App classes? Try putting a breakpoint in the constructor then view the callstack when you hit the break point, it will show when/how the page is being created).

Comment: @slugster HI. Just a quick question. Would this work in a `WPF` application as well? I tried your implementation and I keep getting an "'App'  cannot be the root of a xaml file because it was defined using XAML" error. According to research, what you just did here should not even be possible yet is seems to have worked for at least Four different people.

Comment: @Offer I can't say if this exact technique will work in WPF, but I do use a very similar approach in WPF to extend my views from a base view.

Comment: @slugster Mind if I make a question out of it, and then reference you? That is of course, if you might know a way this could work with app.xaml.cs.

Comment: @Offer By all means create a question, make sure you are really specific about what you are trying to achieve with it.

Comment: @slugster False alarm. Apologies. It was my implementation that was off. This actually works rather well. My problem was making the base class another app.xaml.cs file with the xaml front end. In your example, you only specified a regular class. That bit went over my head. Thanks.