# Create an instance of a window which is not directly derived from WPF Window

Tags: wpf, xaml, inheritance

I have the following hierarchy of classes:

`abstract MyWindowBase : System.Windows.Window` (i.e. the WPF one)

`MyWindow : MyWindowBase`

I want to create a Window of type `MyWindow` as a root element in XAML. I found only this way of doing it:

```xml
<local:MyWindowBase
    x:Class="MyWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    local:x="clr-namespace:MyProjectNamespace">

    <local:MyWindowBase.Resources>...</local:MyWindowBase.Resources>

    ...

</local:MyWindowBase>
```

I.e. I'm specifing my abstract type as the root element, which seems awkward.

I also tried the obvious way:

```xml
<Window
    x:Class="MyWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    ...
</Window>
```

and defining `MyWindow : MyWindowBase` in code-behind, but it clashes with the class definition in the generated file which says `MyWindow : Window`.

Is there a better way?
Thanks

Comment: In XAML you can only create root element of base type, your first way is correct, what is problem with it? There is nothing awkward about your root element being abstract type.

Comment: @Akash - No real problem there, it just looks odd to me. But I'm probably the only one ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this recent post of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6043540/app-xaml-in-class-library/6043702#6043702) which explains exactly this sort of thing - how to derive one page from another (the methodology is exactly the same).

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing preventing you from having whatever hierarchy you want here.  The root element is the base type, and `x:Class` is the generated type you are currently defining.

If you want the specific class to be called `MyWindow` and derived from `MyWindowBase`, your first example is correct:

```
<local:MyWindowBase
    x:Class="MyWindow"
    local:x="clr-namespace:MyProjectNamespace">
```

If you want the specific class to be *derived* from `MyWindow`, then you need a different class name for it:

```
<local:MyWindow
    x:Class="MainWindow"
    local:x="clr-namespace:MyProjectNamespace">
```

Answer (score 0):

It is the normal usage. You are actually doing the same using the default classes created by Visual Studio or Blend.

Notice that you are inheriting from Window, so the actual class is **MainWindow**, but the xaml uses the base class *Window*

C#

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Xaml

```
<Window
  x:Class="MainWindow"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  ...
</Window>
```