# creating a class like App.xaml.cs in Class Library Project

Tags: c#, wpf

So recently; I refactored `Views` to their own `WPF Application` project and I moved my `ViewModel` classes into their own Class Library project. This worked well for keeping my code in order. Then I realised that I didn't have the comfort of the `App.xaml.cs` class.

This class (for me) meant that I could declare all sorts of objects and access them application wide.

i.e: In the App.xaml.cs

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public myDatabaseEntities context { get; set; }

    // App.xaml.cs Constructor
    public App()
    {
        context = new myDatabaseEntities();
    }
}
```

In some random View Model:

```
myDatabaseEntities context = ((App)Application.Current).context;
```

The above allows me to recylce the instance, and comes in particularly handy with Unity's (IoC container) version of lifetime manager.

Thing is, I'm not sure on how to achieve this behaviour within a class Library project. I'm not sure how to create a class that instantiates at runtime. And I have no clue how to pass that `App` class instance around to relevant classes. Any ideas on how to do this? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out all I needed was a regular class without the xaml front end. Then inherit the Application class. And lastly set it as the base class for app.xaml.cs. The answer is already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6043540/app-xaml-in-class-library)

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would keep all the "functionally" related Views and ViewModels together (next to each other). You may want to create class libraries (or modules) based for different functional parts of the application. Also, please refer to this [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg406140.aspx) page on building composite application using WPF and Prism.

---

Coming to your question, have an interface called `IApplication` defined something like this:

```
public interface IApplication
{
    MyDatabaseEntities Context { get; }
}
```

and implement that interface on App class:

```
public partial class App : Application, IApplication
{
    public MyDatabaseEntities Context { get; set; }

    // App.xaml.cs Constructor
    public App()
    {
        Context = new MyDatabaseEntities();
    }
}
```

In your App.xaml.cs, as part of bootstrapping your application register this `App` instance with the container by calling `RegisterInstance` extension method on Unity container:

```
Container.RegisterInstance(typeof (IApplication), this, new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

Now, if your ViewModels take a dependency on `IApplication`, then they will have access to your `App` object and to the Context property via this interface. In future you could expose additional properties like: `Dispatcher`, `Resources`, etc from your `App` object through this interface.